# How to pass variables from one lesscss stylesheet to an included stylesheet?

Tags: css, ruby, less

I am attempting to use [lesscss](http://lesscss.org) to build a templating system where each template has 3 or 4 alternative colour schemes.

So for example, I could have a `red.less` stylesheet that looks like this:

```
@main_colour: #ff0000;
@import 'main.less';
```

So, I only have one `main.less` stylesheet to maintain which contains all the main styles, and uses the variables set for colour codes. I can then create a seperate `colour.less` file for each colour scheme.

Only problem is when I try to do this I get a `Less::VariableNameError` which indicates that LESS is parsing the @imports BEFORE it parses the variables.

Is there a workaround to this or any other way to achieve the same end result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to [your tweet](http://twitter.com/aaronrussell/statuses/7438396734), yes, this would work as you expect in [Sass](http://sass-lang.com). I'm actually kind of surprised that it doesn't work in Less.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. It's not too late to switch to SASS, the only reason I didn't initially is due to the syntax.

I've heard SASS is working on a more CSS-like syntax (like LESS). Do you know how close to reality this is?

Comment: It's actually mostly usable today. The code is available on the scss branch of the repository (http://github.com/nex3/haml/commits/scss). It's not very well-documented at the moment, and it lacks a bit of polish, but it supports almost everything Sass does (the exception being script interpolation in selectors and properties, which is due in the next couple days). If you install that branch, you need merely name your files `.scss` and off you go.

Comment: Thanks. Managed to suss out the SCSS syntax by looking at your tests (although I look forward to the documentation). Seems to work as expected, so unless I get an answer from the LESS chaps pretty pronto I'll be swapping this project over to SASS. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the Less guys wanted to keep the .Less file atomic and independent of external environmental settings. This was what I assumed, but I also didn't like it so our .NET port http://www.dotlesscss.com will allow you to do this by default.

Its not a big change to do in the original Less ruby version and if you fancy tinkering with the source I can point you in the right direction.

Out of interest, without been traitorous to the Less team I quite like the SASS syntax now and there are additional things such as conditional statements and loops that you cant (yet) do with Less.

@nex3 - you guys should stop competing and just work together.

Comment: Thanks. Last night I found a fork of LESS that seems to do what we all want: http://github.com/tablatom/less/commit/0c2c39dc0b3b606b7b8c927a4fd714bf14c1d3e6
However, I'm now reluctant to continue with Less using a 'hacky' approach plus I just get the feeling the SASS team are on top of things a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this isn't a problem any more, or at least not for me using "dotless" for .net?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine now with latest LESS.